# Find a sorting procedure for seven elements that minimises the average number of comparisons performed

Tags: algorithms, sorting, efficiency

In The Art Of Computer Programming, Volume 3, Chapter 5.3.1, Problem 26, Knuth asks one to construct a sorting method that achieves the minimum number of average comparisons for n=7. This means that one needs to find a sorting tree that minimises the total length of all paths from root to every leaf (also known as external path length). A leaf node represents one of the n! permutations of n elements. The average number of comparisons over all possible inputs (all n! permutations) is then simply the external path length divided by n!. The minimal external path length for n=7 is known to be 62416, due to L. Kollar, "Optimal sorting of seven element sets", 1986. Kollar does not seem to construct a sorting tree that achieves this, he only shows that one cannot do better than 62416. Does anyone know whether such a sorting tree has been constructed or is it still an open problem?

Secondary question. How many comparisons does the best known method achieve for n=8? The lower bound for n=8 is 619904, but it is not known if it is obtainable.

Comment: IIRC, Knuth lists optimal sorting networks for some $n$. See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39777/finding-the-two-largest-of-five-small-integers-as-quickly-as-possible/39805#39805) where I dug out the necessary references for $n=5$.

Comment: @Raphael In "Optimal sorting of seven element sets", L. Kollar writes "Knuth
(pp. 197 and 630 in TAOCP) gives pls = 62416 for the best known algorithm." However, the author cites the *first* edition of Volume 3. It may be worth a check. (I don't find this part in the second edition.)

Comment: @hengxin I've seen this reference to the first edition, but can't find it anywhere. Would be great if someone could check.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question.  First you state "the minimal external path length for n=7 is known to be 62416, due to L. Kollar", but then you say that Kollar does not construct a sorting tree that achieves this, only that 62416 is an upper bound.  So how do you know that the minimal external path for n=7 is 62416?  Is that statement a quotation from some source?  If so, what's the source?

Comment: @D.W. you mean "only that ... is a lower bound". But I share your concern: the phrasing suggests that there is proof that the bound is tight.

Comment: @D.W. L. Kollar shows that there is no method that achieves an external path length below 62416. This means that 62416 is a lower bound. I may have misinterpreted Kollar's work, but as far as I can tell he doesn't actually construct a method that achieves 62416. Perhaps Kollar already provides an answer to my question, but I am not seeing it yet.

Comment: Thank you, I understand.  But again: your post states "The minimal external path length for n=7 is known to be 62416, due to L. Kollar".  Where are you getting that from?  Is that a quotation from some other source?  If so, what is the source for that statement?  Or is it a claim/interpretation you are making?  If so, what is your justification for it?  It seems quite odd, because on the one hand you say "What is the minimal external path length for n=7?" and on the other hand in the same question you state "The minimal external path length for n=7 is 62416".  That is confusing.

Comment: The fact that 62416 is minimal is stated in Knuth's answer to problem 26. In his answer Knuth cites the work of Kollar (this is how I found it). Kollar proves that 62416 (flaw=48) is optimal. For n=7 we know the minimal external path length, the question is how to construct a sorting tree that has that length. For n=8 we don't know the minimal external path length, we only know the lower bound of 619904. I have obtained 620724, but it is unlikely to be optimal.

Comment: This was a long time ago, but I agree with @D.W.: The phrasing "The minimal external path length for n=7 is known to be 62416" implies the existence of a solution with this size, and while it's possible that this existence was established via a non-constructive proof, such proofs are very unusual -- by far the most common way to demonstrate existence is with a constructive proof (in this case, by writing down an actual sorting tree).  If no such sorting tree is known to exist, I think you should change the text to "known to be *at least* 62416".

Comment: Yes I think you are right. 62416 is a lower bound. The question remains: has this lower bound actually been achieved in a construction? If not, then what is the best that has been achieved? By the way, the following sequence could help: https://oeis.org/A117627