# Minimal number of comparisons - sorting $6$ elements

Tags: algorithms, sorting, lower-bounds

I've been thinking about sorting $6$ elements with the minimal possible number of comparisons. I can do it in $10$ comparisons but I've no idea if this is optimal. Or is there a better algorithm ?

**Algorithm**
1. Sort $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and $a_4, a_5, a_6$.
Number of comparisons: $3+3=6$.
2. Merge two subarrays.
Number of comparisons: $3 + 3 - 2 = 4$.
Total number of comparisons: $6 + 4 = 10$.

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44981/least-number-of-comparisons-needed-to-sort-order-5-elements?rq=1). In my answer there, I give a reference to the relevant section in TAoCP. What research have *you* done?

Comment: How does step 2 take only 4 comparisons? ​ ​

Comment: You are right, I am wrong.... How to fix it ?

Comment: See, for example, [Daniel Fischer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer)'s answer in [Exactly how many comparisons does merge sort make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535540/exactly-how-many-comparisons-does-merge-sort-make).

Comment: Ok, I know that I was wrong. I think about fixing my algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [A036604](https://oeis.org/A036604), 10 comparisons are indeed optimal. The link probably contains a citation to a paper proving this.

Comment: @user40545 I don't know, but I believe you can verify that yourself.

Comment: Ok, hovewer it is sufficient to analyze decison tree to prove optimality ?  ($log(6!)\ge 10$)

Comment: @user40545 You can do this calculation and see for yourself. Try to be more independent.

Comment: I thnik you are right, I am too dependent.

Answer (score 4):

TL-DR; $10$

Yes, you need to have possibility to ask up to $10$ questions to (comparison) sort an array of $6$ elements.

However, it is possible to create an optimal algorithm that will require no more than 10 questions in worst case, but in average **only** $9.57777$ questions (in $416$ cases $10$ comparisons, in $304$ cases only $9$).

Here is a decision tree for sorting 6 element arrays [a,b,c,d,e,f].
To make it more compressed. I assumed that already $a<b$ , $c<d$ and $e<f$ has been asked (3 comparisons) and in case of false proper pair has been swapped:
[image: Compressed DT for sorting 6 elements]
As you can see, in addition to these 3 comparisons, we need up to 7 more, but often only 6 that gives us the $9.57777$ in average.

Comment: Can you perhaps describe how that algorithm works?  It would be great to see some elaboration/justification on the number you are listing.

Comment: @D.W. it is based on my own research. Not yet published, but you can ping me on priv: michal@post.pl for more details.

Comment: @D.W. I've added example decision tree for you. Cheers!